# Replace/Rename the Online Database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I have got a database of ms-sql server 2005 named mydb, which is being accessed by 7 applications from different location.

i have created its copy named mydbNew and tuned it by applying primary keys, indexes and changing queries in stored procedure.

now i wants to replace old db "mydb" from new db "mydbnew"

please tell me what is the best approach to do it. i though to do changes in web.config but all those application accessing it are not accessible to me, cant go for it.

please provide me experts opinion, so that i can do replace database in minimum time without affecting other db and all its application.

my meaning of saying replace old db by new db is that i wants to rename old db "mydb" to "mydbold" and then wants to remname my new db "mydbnew" to "mydb"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan will work but it does carry a high risk, especially since I'm assuming this is a system that has users actively changing data, which means your copy won't have the same level of updated content in it unless you do a cut right before go-live. Your best bet is to migrate your changes carefully into the live system during a low traffic / maintenance period and extensively test it once your done. Prior to doing this, or the method you mentioned previously, backup **everything**.

All of the changes you described above can be made to an online database without the need to actually bring it down. However, some of those activities will change the way in which the data is affected by certain actions (changes to stored procs), that means that during the transition the behaviour of the system or systems may be unpredicatable and therefore you should either complete this update at a low point in day to day operations or take it down for a maintenance window.

Sql Server comes with a function to make a script file out of you database, you can also do this manually but clicking on the object you want to script and selecting the Script -> CREATE option. Depending on the amount of changes you have to make it may be worthwhile to script your whole new database (By clicking on the new database and selecting **Tasks** -> **Generate Scripts...** and selecting the items needed).

If you want to just script out the new things you need to add individually then you simply click on the object you want to script, select the **Script `<object>` as** -> then select **DROP and CREATE** to if you want to kill the original version (like replacing a stored proc) or select **CREATE** to if your adding new stuff.

Once you have all the things you want to add/update as a script your then ready to execute that against the new database. This would be the part where you backup **everything**. Once your happy everything is backed up and the system is in maintenance or a low traqffic period, you execute the script. There may be a few problems when you do this, you will need to fix these as quickly as possible (usually mostly just 'already exisits' errors, thats why drop and create scripts are good) and if anything goes really wrong restore your backups and try again (after figuring out what happened and how to fix it).

Make no mistake if you have a lot of changes to make this could be a long process, or it could take mere minutes, you just need to adapt if things go wrong and be sure to cover yourself with backups/extensive prayer. Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for quick reply. i will do it when there will be low traffic so please tell me step should i follow to perform this

Comment: Not a problem, I've added some steps into my answer.

Comment: JonVD: thanks a lot, my both database old and new are on same server. i just want rename old database and then wants to rename new database to name of old one.

Comment: JonVD: can't we do it by like: take old database offline and rename it to another name like "oldDb" and then take new db offline and rename it to the name of old database and than we can take both online ?

Comment: Yes you can but it can be a bit risky, as I said your new db probably won't have up to date data in it. If it does then by all means just switch the names (after you backup) and you should be fine.